# Position div after another element which is in a form

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position

Hello I would like to position absoulte a div after a filedset in a form but the form has another container element and the fieldst's height is not fixed it is changing by content inside it.
I made this with jQuery but is doesn't work. Oh and I can't put the div inside the form because that div contains another form.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
  var heightOfform = document.getElementById("form").scrollHeight;
  var heightOffsomethingafter = document.getElementById("somethingafter").scrollHeight;
  document.getElementById("divtoposition").css('top', (heightOfform-heightOffsomethingafter)+'px');
  });
</script>
<style>
#all {position:relative;}
#divtoposition {position:absolute;}
</style>
<div id="all">
<div id="divtoposition"><form></form></div>
<div id="formcontainer">
  <form id="form">
    <fieldset id="afterthis"></fieldset>
    <div id="somethingafter"></div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not just put `#somethingafter` below `#form` and then put `#divtoposition` between `#form` and `#somethingafter`? If not, can you explain why you need it in this format?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a complicated answer but could you explain why the div you want to position has a form in it? What does it do? Can it be done another way? You can't put a form in a form so that's out. You can set the top of the DivToPosition to say 100px, then have jquery get the height of the fieldset. IF the fieldset is say 150px in height you can have Js add 150 to the 100 and now DivToPosition had a height of 250px;

```
 <script>
$(function(){
var divtopositionTop = 100,
fieldsetHeight = $('#afterthis').height();
   $('#divtoposition').css('top', divtopositionTop+fieldsetHeight+'px');
})
</script>
```

Just an example it can be done. Must be done on doc ready so the height is set. However this may cause a quick position change where the elem moves from 1 position to another as the style is applied.

Comment: The form in the divtoposition is a login box and the other form is an order form but as I said the fieldset height is changing with the content in it. but actually I got my code work just had to change document.getElementById("divtoposition") to $('#divtoposition') and now it works but the div is over the 'somethingafter' even if I set a margin for '#somethingafter' or for the '#form' I could set -Xpx to the top position but I don't know that whether this will work on all resolution or any height of content or not.